# How to show all items in repeating table in sharepoint list

Tags: list, infopath, sharepoint-list, repeating-table

Please how can i ensure that all rows of a repeating table in my infopath form is populated on SharePoint (and not only the first row).

Comment: InfoPath? this is dead product, use html, js, css...

Comment: The above comment is not very helpful. Neither is this one...

Infopath may be deprecated, however MS still have Infopath Services as an Office 365 option, so it is hardly dead.